# Creating a table in Excel to track performance on 2 data points

Tags: excel, performance

I am looking to create an excel table so i can review my colleagues performance on a certain area in work.
The two measurement areas are Resolved Problems and Total time spent. I can pull this info from a dashboard at the end of the week and manually input it to excel.

We have 6 members of the team and i want to be able to input this data as weekly totals per user.

I will then use this data to track trends like who is resolving most problems, who is doing the least. Who spends the most time on problems and who spends the least.

I am not sure the best way to go about this data capture in excel.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this something that you would right click, select pivot table, and pivot my person, value column of time, sort by time?